# Oracle Apex Text Field Character Limit

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an issue with the Text fields items character length.
Set it up to 500 (as seen on the snap below) but I get this error everytime:

ORA-12899: value too large for column "WKSP_TECHLS"."SURVEY_TEST_T"."ANSWER" (actual: 500, maximum: 100)

[image: item_attributes]

Am I missing something here perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason why, item was being inserted into a column with a 100 character limit. Had to expand it to 500, thanks